# Invoke javascript function when data is ready (in ERB view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a rails view, foo.html.erb

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function showData(data) {
          // ..do stuff here
     }
  </script>
<% end %

<% if !@data.nil? %%>
  <div id="where_data_will_go"></div>
<% end %
```

the "@data" is JSON from the server (i.e. the server does, render :json @data).

How can I call "showData" when @data is not null (i.e. I have some data)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% unless @data.nil? %>
  <script>showData('<%= escape_javascript(@data) %>');</script>
<% end %>
```

Note that the function in the head must also be inside `<script>`-tags.

Comment: Thanks, although I just realized that when I use:

  render :json => @data

in my controller, Firefox 3 wants to open the page as a file b/c the content-type is application/json.

Comment: You can also render the data as JSON directly in the view inside the function if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox 3 can't handle a content-type of application/json (i.e. it wants to download it as a file, it won't open it natively) I had to do something else.

My controller has two methods:

```
def foo
end

def foo_json
 # get data and render json
 render :json => @data
end
```

My view now has an empty  which will store the JSON once I do something with it. I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(....)
});
```

to populate my div when the page loads which works great. Thanks Radek for your suggestion.